# What is the difference between a nonessential and essential clause?

Tags: grammar, phrases, differences, clauses

According to [this](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/essentialclause.htm), adding a specific noun to a sentence can make a clause nonessential.

Example - 

Freddie hopes to return to the city **where he met a woman with haunting green eyes.**

vs.
 

Freddie hopes to return to Cairo, **where he met a woman with haunting green eyes**.

 Even if Cairo is the proper noun and we know where Freddie hopes to return, we still miss out on "where he met a woman with haunting green eyes". Why does adding the place make this a nonessential phrase?

Comment: The postmodifier 'where he met a woman with haunting green eyes' is necessary ('essential') to specify which city (within the context of the sentence, not geographically). The clause is an _identifier_. // In the second example, 'where he met a woman with haunting green eyes' is just tacking on a relevant piece of information; it is not 'necessary' to identify 'which Cairo we are talking about' (which would be nonsense). But I can talk about 'the Cheadle which has a branch of the Leek Building Society', as there are two Cheadles quite close together, one with and one without a branch.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth May I ask - do you, in your commenting, use slanted lines (//) to denote a new paragraph ?

Comment: @Nigel J Yes. The formatting options are dire, but I refuse to give an 'answer' where I feel I must closevote.

Comment: I would argue that the specific noun has nothing to do with this. It's the use of the comma. What if Freddie had been living in the country? If so, then "Freddie hopes to return to the city," on its own, *could* be the only essential information—if there is a comma afterwards.

Comment: Because there is only one Cairo, so it hardy needs defining in the relative clause. The comma correctly marks the clause as a non-defining one.